# Can a device with Zigbee Light Link ZLL connect to a Zigbee Home Automation HA network

Tags: zigbee

Zigbee Light Link is a subset of Zigbee Home Automation. My question is : is it possible to add a device with ZLL profile to a Zigbee Home Automation Network?

**UPDATE**
I have a ZLL based device in the form of [Mesh Bee](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Mesh_Bee), When I query available networks through the AT command it lists the Mesh Bee that has been set as a coordinator.

I have another device that is using Home Automation Profile and is a coordinator, But it doesn't get listed in the list of available networks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  That's kinda the whole point behind ZLL.

Update to Update:
That's why I don't use third party APIs. When something goes wrong it's not worth the effort to figure out someone else's code to fix the bug.

Comment: great, I have updated my question. If this is the case I am not able to get a HA profile coordinator in list of available networks! what could be wrong with this!

Comment: Thanks . I have one more question ... If a system is using standard HA profile, would I be able to join any HA profile device to it ?